# Use Case in SQL for insert or update

Tags: sql-server

I have temporary table that contains multiple rows and original table with below structure :

### temp : desc,id

Original :name,id,rate

I have to check if id of one row matches the original one then i have to update the rate in Original else i have to insert row in original and this all should be happening in a loop as we have multiple records in temporary table.
I am working in SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Look at MERGE and do not think in loops or other procedural approaches... SQL is set based...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop; you can do this with an update followed by an insert:

```
UPDATE Original
SET rate = /* whatever the new rate is */
FROM Original
INNER JOIN temp on Original.id = temp.id

INSERT INTO Original (name, id, rate)
SELECT desc, id, /* whatever the rate is */ FROM temp
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Original)
```

Comment: I am able to perform the operation using this but I have multiple rows in my excel which have same id but there is one more parameter itemid which is different.This itemid is present in items table and it has no relation with Original table.So right now i am concerned with Original table to get data inserted and updated and Original table do not have any itemid.I am getting project in applying this query as if i have same name,id and rate but different itemid in my sheet it will simply go into update part.So i need to check one more condition that the cooresponding itemid exists in items table

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MERGE can be a good option for you :

```
-- MERGE statement with the join conditions specified correctly.
USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

Straight pick from below link

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx